# How to access Monodroid resources from .java file splash screen

Tags: android, android-layout, resources, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement a .java splash screen in my Monodroid app in Visual Studio, anyway I want the splash screen to get it's content view from a resouces layout. I'm trying to get it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.AppSplash);
```

Also tried with:

```
setContentView(Resource.layout.AppSplash);
```

And also:

```
setContentView("@layout/AppSplash");
```

And I get error messages like this:

```
package R does not exist
```

Where R changes for Resources or:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setContentView(java.lang.String)
location: class SwimmerTimesCalc.SplashActivity
    setContentView("@layout/AppSplash");
```

When I try the @layout/AppSplash option

How can I access the Monodroid resources to set the layout of my Splash Screen?

Comment: Could probably someone from the Xamarin team comment on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to access the resources, since the debugger couldnt access the resources I went to the generated resources file that is in the project folder under \obj[This can be debug or release]\android\src and it's called R. While browsing that file I found the layout I was trying to use like this:

```
public static final int appsplash1=0x7f030002;
```

I took the resource value from there that is 0x7f030002 and used it like this:

```
setContentView(0x7f030002);
```

Anyway as the resources file is autogenerated, adding another layout that goes alphabetically before this may require to do this proccess again.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Creating_a_Splash_Screen) should help you get started.

If you were wanting to use a layout specifically for creating your own splash screen and then using that resource to display it in your activity then you can use something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SplashScreenLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SplashDefault"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity you can just set the content view.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);
    }
```

Comment: Not really what I was asking for, anyway I think I'll have to make my splashscreen with a monodroid activity instead of a .java file, thank you for your time

Comment: I realize that my answer wasn't to the question you asked, but it seems like you are making it harder than it should be to just implement a splash screen.  I'm not seeing any reason why you just wouldn't create a new one, for me it was infinitely easier than having to find the id value of the resource and making sure it's correct everytime when mono will do that for you when its recompiled.

Comment: It's for speed optimization that I require a java splash screen, as I'm working with monodroid, monodroid apps take a while to startup and I'm also getting some data on startup, so I needed this java splash screen to show the user that the app is working at the moment they start it

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem here. One can find the id of the resource in runtime by it's name and folder like this:

```
int iconResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

So, in the Java files one can use such lookups instead of R.drawable.icon and it will work.

This however is slower (because the lookup is implemented inefficiently on Android) and one would still hard-code the names of resources as strings. If one moves or renames resources in the Mono project, the Java files won't know about this.

Also, one has to type all resource names in lower case, cuz Mono converts the name from .NET-style like "Icon.png" to Android style "icon.png".